# Merge EJBQL query with CriteriaBuilder object

Tags: java, jpa, jasper-reports, ejbql

Is there a simple way to merge a existing ejbql query with a existing CriteriaBuilder object?

I have on the one side a jasper report with ejbql query 
and on another side are applications function and object rights as a CriteriaBuilder object.

My idee was:

I take a report query -> add function rights statement -> execute both in one go

Answer (score 0):

Probably best to stick with one or the other.

In EclipseLink both end up as EclipseLink Expression objects.  From a JPQL query, you can get the DatabaseQuery and add to its selectionCriteria with another Expression, which you could generate from Criteria.

Comment: Thank you, I try to verify your solution